# How to publish a website on Nuxt 3 + Laravel on the Internet?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm making a website on `Nuxt 3` + `Laravel` (backend, api), and now I need to publish it on the internet. But when calling `npm run build`, `Nuxt` generates the output folder of the following structure:

```
public
server
nitro.json
```

That is, there are no static files in this folder (such as `index.html`), which the server expects to see.

I need:

1. Publish the website on the Internet on a regular hosting.
2. Be able to edit the site on a local server and then quickly transfer the changes to the hosting (for example, via git).

Questions:

1. What is the algorithm for publishing the `Nuxt 3` website on the Internet?
2. Is a regular hosting suitable for this? What settings do I need to make on the hosting to make the site work?
3. How to publish the server api (`Laravel`)?
4. Now the api is located in a separate folder and is considered a separate site. When publishing, will it also be a separate site? If so, how to address him? By some external domain?

Comment: After building, the `public` folder contains HTML CSS and JS, they are the static files to your website. You can copy paste them to a webserver to host.

Comment: @RajDave The `public` folder contains:

"__nuxt"; 
"favicon.ico"

Nothing `index.html` . In the `_nuxt` folder - only `js` and `css`.